# sum two properties of an item in list (javascript)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list which has items like this

```
{ quantity: '', price: '', amount: '' }
```

These items are added dynamically, My question is, is it possible to sum quantity and price to come up with amount value such that the amount value will also change with regard to price or quantity ?

Comment: Every time price, quantity and/or amount change in your object, you have to update your sum by firing a change event and then do the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you need a getter function for amount:

```
a = ({
  quantity: '',
  price: '',
  get amount() {
    return +this.quantity + +this.price;
  }
})
```

then you may access `a.amount` for the sum of quantity and price.

Answer (score 1):

Though I think the operation should be 'multiplication' instead of 'additon'.
Try the following:

```js
var array = [{ quantity: 10, price: 200, amount: '' },{ quantity: 5, price: 100, amount: '' }]
var newArray = array.map(function(elem, index){
 array[index].amount = array[index].quantity + array[index].price
 return;
});
 
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `vuejs` you can easily achieve your objective by using `[computed][1]` properties.

Example:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      quantity: '',
      price: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    amount () {
      return this.quantity + this.price
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `computed` properties can't be set like `this.computedProp = someValue` and they are not `functions`, they can be used just like `data` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new component that related to the item in the list

```html
var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#example',
      data: {
        quantity: '', 
        price: ''
      },
      computed: {
        amount: function(){
          return this.quantity * this.price
        }
        
      }
    })
```

And then create a computed property based on the quantity and price.

Comment: Although I too personally agree with the sentiment of `this.quantity * this.price` but OP asked for sum for some reason. :/

Comment: Oh I see, I'll stick with this as it makes no sense to sum quantity and price. OP probably did a typo there. Our answers are the same, posted at the same time :P

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of **plain javascript** options. I did not mention any Vue-specific stuff.

The easiest one, to me, would be to add a `getAmount`-method to your objects, which would return the amount based on your other two properties.
**e.g.**

```
var item = {
  quantity: 3,
  price: 5.00,
  getAmount: function () {
    return this.quantity * this.price
  }
}
```

Although I'd with `null` as default values.
A second option is to use object descriptors. You can create an object using `Object.create()` or add properties to an already existing object using `Object.defineProperty()`. Both of these methods allow you to pass an object descriptor, where you can define a `getter` for your property, which will calculate your desired value based on your other fields.
**e.g.**

```
var item = Object.create({
  quantity: null,
  price: null,
}, {
  amount: {
    get: function () { return this.quantity*this.price }
  }
})
```

Now, the `amount` property will return `quantity * price`, just by doing `item.amount`.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the price based on quantity simply use `{{ item.price * item.quantity }}`. I assume you don't want to clutter your database with an unneeded total field :-)

**Example (including total price)**

```js
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data: {
        list: [
            { name: 'foo', quantity: 2, price: 20 },
            { name: 'bar', quantity: 3, price: 150 },
            { name: 'baz', quantity: 1, price: 80 }
        ]
    },
    computed: {
        total(){ return this.list.reduce( (total, item) => item.price * item.quantity + total  ,0);},
    }
})
```

```css
ul {list-style:none;}
li:last-child { border-top:1px solid;border-bottom:3px double;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>



<div id="app">
   <ul>
        <li v-for="item in list">
            {{ item.name}}: {{ item.price * item.quantity}}
        </li>
        <li>Total: {{ total }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```